# Reopen last closed tab in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to reopen the last closed tab in Visual Studio? Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> in FireFox and Chrome?

Comment: Although this question is not for VSCode, google still brought me here... so yeah, for VSCode `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`T` will reopen last closed file.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can with the [Visual studio Power Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Comment: 2017 extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017 which includes the Power Commands. It‘s not working right now as I‘m writing and the bug report is here https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-PPT/issues/208

Comment: @bugybunny You can try this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamWulkiewicz.UndoCloseDocument it should also work with VS2017.

Comment: 2022  this didn't work for me, but  `SHIFT + CTRL + T`  worked

Answer (score 220):

This is not exactly an equivalent, but it can be helpful, so I would mention it.

There is a much simpler way actually, which is to navigate backward (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>). Even if the file is closed, VS opens up the file in a new tab. Of course this is useful only in opening the closed tab immediately after you have closed the tab (ie, if you haven't navigated anywhere else much).

---

**Update:**
This is now possible in VS 17.3. By using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keyboard shortcut, or navigating to the menu item under *Window > Restore Closed Tab*. Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-3-is-now-available/

Comment: This really only works though if you were working in that file immediately before closing it.

Comment: This even works if you have closed all the tabs. Just need to "Keep Open / Pin" each tab else it will keep replacing the tab.

Comment: The Standard toolbar - under the Navigate backward arrow icon - shows the list of files that Ctrl+- loops over. It lists open files even if you did not edit them. At least in VS2017.

Comment: @pasx, you need not edit but you have to navigate to the file (i.e. open the file) for ctrl - to work. Imagine you closed a background tab that you didn't navigate to. You can't ctrl- to that file. Hope VS addresses this at some point.

Comment: if you accidentally selected "Close other tabs" when you meant "Close tab" how to get all the other tabs back?

Comment: @EdRandall haha, raise a request in visual studio community.. May get noticed..

Answer (score 79):

Also consider **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**.

(push <kbd>Alt</kbd> and hold it, now while holding, press <kbd>F</kbd> and then press <kbd>F</kbd> again).

This will open the `Recent Files` menu.
There, you can use arrow keys to select a file and open it by hitting Enter, or just use your mouse.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, this is the `File` -> `Recent Files` menu.

Comment: simple and good way but it fails when you closed 1st file if 11 files or more opened

Comment: Simple and good enough for "classical" files but unable to reopen other tabs like source control explorer for instance.

Comment: For anyone confused: You hit `Alt+F, F`. You do not press Alt again. You can release Alt after the first Alt+F or you can still hold it down. But do not press it again.

Comment: you are god @trident

Answer (score 30):

If you're using VS 2008, [PowerCommands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) offers a "Undo Close" pane, featuring your recently closed documents, or like David said, check the File menu. PowerCommands doesn't limit the number of files it shows, though.

Comment: Thank you for explaining _how_ to access it through PowerCommands.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 19):

I don't know of way to open the last closed tab, but you can open  your most recent file through your File Menu and the top one should be your most recently closed tab.

Comment: Recent files list is populated with files opened out of a solution scope

Comment: Recent files list does contain files opened out of a solution scope, along with most files opened with in the current solution.  With the most recent file being listed at the top.

Comment: The ordering is not most recent closed, but rather most recently opened, which is sadly not ideal.

Answer (score 12):

In Visual Studio Code 2020 you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which is associated with *Reopen Closed Editor*. This should do what you're expecting.

Comment: You are speaking of VS Code.

Comment: In VS Code the default is:
`{ "key": "ctrl+shift+t", "command": "workbench.action.reopenClosedEditor" }`
Ctrl+Shift+P  "Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"
Add this value if it's not your default.

Comment: In VS 2020, Shift+Ctrl+T will open the "Go to Files' dialogue. This is only true for VS Code

Answer (score 11):

in VS 2010 "PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010"

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/

Adds a command "Undo Close"

Answer (score 11):

You can actually do this (at least in Visual Studio 2019) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd> which opens a little window which shows the last opened windows.

[Source](https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-open-recently-closed-files.htm)

As [NotAPro pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853038/reopen-last-closed-tab-in-visual-studio#comment117053815_59267558), the combination I mentioned seems to have changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Same in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: As of typing, this is Ctrl+1,Ctrl+R; not Ctrl+T,Ctrl+R

Answer (score 4):

Once you use VS 2022 V.17.3 it is pretty simple:

CTRL+K, CTRL+Z

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code Version 1.80.1

1. Go to Settings
2. Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Find workbench.action.localHistory.restoreViaPicker
4. Set Short Cut Key For it.
5. Press the desired shortcut key.
6. Select the previously closed file with correct time of at which you saved file.
   File Restored Hurrah!