# Reopen closed tab in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In my web browser (Google Chrome), after a tab is closed, I can re-open it with the menu item 'reopen closed tab'. (Firefox has this feature too, 'undo close tab'.)

How can I do undo closing a tab in Visual Studio 2012?

---

I found this similar question from 2009, but the accepted answer doesn't work for Visual Studio 2012. [Reopen last closed tab in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853038/reopen-last-closed-tab-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) extension has the Undo Close functionality. Some of the older extensions designed for VS2010 may not work correctly in VS2012, also quite a lot of functionality from these extensions has been incorporated in VS2012.

In Visual Studio 2012/2013, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo close.

Comment: So what's the shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

Did you tried with the 2010 version of PowerCommands ?

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/

http://www.patridgedev.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/UndoCloseSettings.png