# Re-open closed tab (undo close) in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

While there were various ways of re-opening closed tabs in [Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194303/48700) and [Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194925/48700), it appears that those plug-ins have not evolved into the Visual Studio 2013 add-in world.

Since the [Productivity Power Tools gallery page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) specifically mentions "Visual Studio Professional 2012 *(and above)*" (emphasis mine), I tried installing it, but it isn't finding VS 2013 as an eligible target. I'm guessing "above" refers to the product tiers of Visual Studio 2012.

[image: No Visual Studio 2013 option on Productivity Power Tools install]

Looking at the Q&A on that same page shows a lot of requests for 2013 support as well.

Is there a method of adding undo-close functionality to Visual Studio 2013, either built-in or using a new/updated add-in?

Comment: The Q+A tab for that extension is already filled with a hundred "where's VS2013 support?" comments.  I doubt they need more, check again a month from now.

Comment: I don't mention its lack of VS2013 support simply to draw attention to it; it is just some background on an approach that didn't work and lead me to seek out the help of the Stack Overflow community. I don't need that exact extension to be the answer, I would gladly take an alternative approach if someone has one.

Comment: What about Visual Studio 2014?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Productivity Power Tools 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace?SRC=VSIDE) is now available for Visual Studio 2013.

Along with a bunch of other features, it still offers `Edit.UndoClose` functionality as previous version had.

You can find the command under Tools->Options and give it whatever shortcut you want (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, in this case, to make it like a web browser re-open tab shortcut).

[image: Edit.UndoClose command in Visual Studio 2013 by way of the Productivity Power Tools 2013]

Comment: The default shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+Z` and you need to enable the "Power Commands" extension under Tools → Options → Productivity Power Tools, then you need to enable the "Undo Close" command under PowerCommands → Commands.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't have the "Undo Close" window inside "View" / "Other Windows" like VS2012 has...

Comment: 2015 version https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d

Comment: Undo Close is enabled but the command is not executed. I even tried assigning different shortcuts but the command is never executed (checked with the "Learn the shortcut" extension that logs all executed commands)

Answer (score 27):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> should jump you back into the tab you closed. You may have to do that several times.

Also <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is a quick way to jump to recent files, your file might be there. Keep holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> while pressing <kbd>F</kbd> twice.

Comment: Very useful shortcut to know. For anyone curious, that translates to `View.NavigateBackward`. It does a great job stepping back through locations you have previously had your cursor. I use it quite a bit as well as `Edit.UndoClose` because they tend to meet different use cases. If I ctrl+tab to a tab and then close it, this will bring me right back into the closed tab. But, if I close a window without "navigating" to it (e.g., middle click a tab), I still need to re-open that tab some other way.

Comment: I like `ALT-F-F` +1