# Turn off visual studio 2013 intellisence links. Control + mouse click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

It's very hard in new visual studio copy and paste part of text because when **control** is clicked all types, methods, variables will be hilighted like links. 
So i cannot quickly use **control**+**c** and  **control**+**v** because when control is hold and you select with mouse part of method name visual studio will open method definition pane and then fragment from buffer will be pasted there!

[image]

This is very disturbing and annoying. Any way to turn this off?

Comment: I'm not following. Can't you just let your mouse button when tapping control+c? You select, then copy, not both simultaneously.

Comment: @Tarec I am starting hold ctrl before actually selecting text. I do this automatically and very quickly. And in most cases i use double click on word to replace. In all this cases new dialog is opened. Which I want to turn off actually.

Comment: You should be able to modify your IntelliSense options in your tools menu.  *TOOLS->Options->Text Editor->the specific language(C#) ->IntelliSense.*

Comment: @Kelix I dont see how turn off those links there.

Comment: There is a checkbox for the auto complete at the top of the options available from where @Kelix points you, uncheck that.

Comment: @JohnP links still there. Even when autocomplete is off.

Comment: @Evgeny - Don't know what to tell you then, you have a unique install. I'm using VS 2012 and that turns it off for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was uninstalled productivity tools and it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I tracked this down to the Productivity Power Tools 2013 as well. Instead of uninstalling it like [@Evengy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26777989/48700), if you use it for something else like [Undo Close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20131752/48700), you can just disable the option for that feature.

(Note: you'll need to restart Visual Studio for the changes to take effect.)

[image: Productivity Power Tools settings screenshot]