# All tabs are cleared if I reopen my solution where at least one xaml file was opened

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I found something wrong with my Visual Studio 2012.
First, I open a VS solution file which connects to some files.
Next, if I open at least one **xaml** file from them, then reopen the solution, all my tabs will be cleared to empty. I guess the problem might be related to the VS setting.

*Note:

1. In my experiments, any xaml file comes from the WPF project.
2. If none of xaml files opened before, last tabs keep normally.

Comment: what do you mean by tabs here? Are those the opened classes or the xaml pages?

Comment: I meant xaml pages. If all are CS files, it's save.

Comment: Did you try pinning your tabs after opening them in your solution?

Comment: I just tried pinning, but it also doesn't work. @Kulasangar , do you have the same issue in your visual studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running your VS as admin according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b829b6e0-700e-4fff-b955-0bf6bc44fa13/vs2010-does-not-open-recently-opened-files?forum=visualstudiogeneral) thread.

[Re-open closed tab (undo close) in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864290/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried but still didn't work. Thanks for your solution anyway. I think I need to reinstall my VS...

Comment: @J.E. try repairing it rather than re-installing.

Comment: Before repairing, I bookmark all xaml files opened on tabs instead.