# Re-open closed tab (undo close) in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

As per this old question: [Re-open closed tab (undo close) in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864290/re-open-closed-tab-undo-close-in-visual-studio-2013/24283028)
I want to open closed tabs just like in a browser. I used power tools plugin for 2017 to get it working but does not seem to work in 2019. Surprised VS still don't have this feature native. Any other work around for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Visual Studio Document Reopen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=major.VSDocumentReopen) extension reopens the last closed documents with (CTRL + SHIFT + T).

Answer (score 1):

[Power Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) extension supports Visual Studio 2019:

> Reopens a closed document, returning the cursor to its last position.
>   Recently closed documents can be reopened through the Edit menu and
>   clicking Undo Close or by using the Ctrl + Shift + Z shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As i said, i have tried this and it does not work. Have seen others commenting it does not work too. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in shortcut CTL + 1, R that will open all recent files. However I prefear to change it to CTL + T. You can do that by opening settings -> keyboard -> Edit.GoToRecentFile.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in a way, possible to do it without extensions … by using the "go to" functionality:

You press <kbd>CTRL + T</kbd>, put <kbd>r</kbd> in the box that comes up and it'll show you a list of "recent files". It seems closing or opening a file puts that file at the top of the list.

Source: https://www.meziantou.net/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-open-recently-closed-files.htm.

Documentation on some more fancy stuff you can do on the "go to" function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2019